# React Getting default value from an input type text and setting it as a state

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have some input text fields that I want to fill in for the user, as it will be default values for a configuration.

How can I transfer that over to a state variable in React?

I have:

```
<input type="number" style={header} value = "5" onChange={this.handleChange('blah')}></input> <br />
```

as an input field, where you can see I set the value to be 5. How can I transfer this to the state variable 'blah' located in constructor:

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        blah: '',
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve like this :

```
state = {
    blah : "hello"
  }
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({blah:e.target.value})
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <input type="text" 
      value = {this.state.blah} 
      onChange={this.handleChange}></input> 

    );
  }
```

Live example : https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-kare-50cbn

For more understanding you can refer this doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html